# HA Proxy for EJBCA Web Admin using certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, pkcs#12, ejbca

I have a new fresh EJBCA installation and I made a copy of it in the same machine in order to test an HA Proxy as a load balancer.

I do the necessary in wildfly config in order to use different port for each instance

I followed this link from the official documentation https://www.ejbca.org/docs/Setting_up_a_HA_Proxy_in_front_of_EJBCA.html

My HAProxy config looks like :

```
frontend ejbca_front
    bind *:8443
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend ca_nodes

backend ca_nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server web01 localhost:8453 check
    server web02 localhost:8448 check
```

But when I try to go to the ejbca admin interface on port 8443 the page is not reachable

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : The line "option ssl-hello-chk" was not necessary in my use case.